# c# mvc3 page layout changes when there is a reponse.redirect command

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a slight problem my code works fine but it re-sizes my entire page. The code I have is:

```
else if (searchString == "")
{
    Response.Write("<script>window.alert('Nothing Has Been Entered.' </script>");
}
```

Now the thing is i have a search box if it is empty this message appears but when i press the ok button on the message that appears it re-sizes my page layout and makes everything bigger. Is there a way to stop this from happening I am using C# and in ASP.NET and MVC3

Comment: Post your view+controller code. any way, You aren't suppose to write directly to the response in MVC application

Comment: I dont think my code for my view and controller will be helpful because all i want is a simple message that shows a user that when leaving something blank from a search box should show a error I have goggled it and for some reason I cant find anything :/ the above code is enough because it shows what i want to get. In my application above the else if is just some code for the search box which works fine. Thank you for the replay and all your help guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use `Response.Write` in asp.net mvc. MVC doesn't work like that. Instead, set your message in the ViewData like this:

```
else if (searchString == "") {
    ViewData["MyMessage"] = "Nothing Has Been Entered.";
}
```

Then in your .cshtml page, show it like this:

```
@if (ViewData["MyMessage"] != null) {
    <script type="text/javascript">
         alert('@ViewData["MyMessage"]');
    </script>
}
```